# Django-tenants difference between connection.tenant and request.tenant

Tags: django, django-tenants

I am working on a multitenant Django application using `django-tenants` library. Getting the current tenant object can be done through one of the two ways:

1. This can be used anywhere:

```
    from django.db import connection
    tenant = connection.tenant
```

2. This can be used in views.py only where the `request` object is accessible:

```
    tenant = request.tenant
```

So, why we have it added to `request` while it is globally accessible on the `connection` object?

Answer (score 1):

1. Request tenant is for web requests to indicate which schema/tenant the requests belong to. So that isolation is possible. Eg: `demo.localhost` you're request belongs to demo tenant.
2. Connection tenant is for the runtime environment which applies to the SQL queries so that you'll get the isolated query results for specific tenant.

Using request tenant you can set db connection to specific tenant.